# Refactor (C) pseudo code to remove goto

Tags: java, c, goto

What is the best practise refactoring for this in Java?

```
while (1) {
  // initialisation

  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPT; i++) {
    if (try_something()) goto step2;
  }
  continue;

step2:  
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPT; i++) {
    if (try_next_thing()) goto step3;
  }
  continue;

step3:
  ...
}
```

Comment: As for the suppressing of gotos, other provided answers.
As for the java part : what are your expectations ? Are you looking for object-oriented refactoring ?

Comment: No, just simple flow control.

Comment: Why refactor this code? The code is readable and easy to follow. Why do you wan't to remove the `goto` statements?

Comment: @Bart Java doesn't have goto.

Comment: [:blush:] I misread your question. I thought you wanted to refactor in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first want to determine what the code is trying to accomplish:

- Do the following over and over:
- Call try_something() up to MAX_ATTEMPT times, restarting if it never returns true.
- Call try_next_thing() up to MAX_ATTEMPT times, restarting if it never returns true.

Then, write code that does that, e.g.:

```
while (true) {

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPT && !try_something(); ++ i)
        ;
    if (i == MAX_ATTEMPT)
        continue;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPT && !try_next_thing(); ++ i)
        ;
    if (i == MAX_ATTEMPT)
        continue;

    // etc.

}
```

There are plenty of other ways to express that. For example, you could break each step into a method, and take advantage of the fact that && will stop evaluating it's arguments when one is false:

```
boolean doFirstThing () {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPTS && !try_something(); ++ i)
        ;
    return i < MAX_ATTEMPTS;
}

boolean doSecondThing () {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPTS && !try_other_thing(); ++ i)
        ;
    return i < MAX_ATTEMPTS;
}

// then, elsewhere
while (true)
    doFirstThing() && doSecondThing();
```

Or whatever. I'm not sure if I'd call the latter a "best practice" as it is a bit obfuscated (that's not to say it's not appropriate in certain situations), but it's just an example. In general, when porting to another language: Analyze original -> what is it supposed to do? -> reimplement in target language. Priority is code correctness, second (but not far behind) is clarity.

Comment: Thanks, I already did your first solution, but I didn't like the scope of i.  Looks like I'll need to stick with it, as there's no better answer here.

Comment: The thing is, the original code used `goto` because no information about the success/retry state was available outside the retry loops. No matter what solution you use, if you want to avoid `goto` style jumps, you need some way of carrying information about the state of one step over to the next step.

Answer (score 2):

For a literal, but not the best translation you can do. Using break as a goto is not a good idea unless you have to generate the code and there is no simple way around it.

```
while (true) {
    // initialisation

    step2:
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPT; i++) {
            if (try_something()) break step2;
        }
        continue;
    }

    step3:
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPT; i++) {
            if (try_next_thing()) break step3;
        }
        continue;
    }

    step4:
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd be tempted to encapsulate the steps and use something like a state machine:

```
enum Step {
    STEP1 {
        @Override
        public Step attempt() {
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPT; i++) {
                if (try_something()) return STEP2; // advance to next step
            }
            return STEP1; // return to step 1
        }
    },
    STEP2 {
        @Override
        public Step attempt() {
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPT; i++) {
                if (try_next_thing()) return STEP3; // advance to next step
            }
            return STEP1; // return to step 1
        }
    },
    STEP3 { /* etc. */ },
    . . .
    ;
    public abstract Step attempt();
}
```

Then (if I understand the original spaghetti logic) you can write your loop as:

```
Step step = Step.STEP1;
while (1) {
    // initialisation

    step = step.attempt();
}
```

Comment: +1, much nicer than my attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best solution, but I usually would do:

```
boolean success = false;

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPT && !success; i++) {
    success = try_something()
}

if (success) {
    success = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPT && !success; i++) {
        success = try_next_thing();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You'll want to stop the loop after the first found success.

Comment: @Lundin that's why the loop condition adds the `&& !success` addon.

Comment: Sorry, I will look carefully next time :)

Answer (score 0):

I would first refactor the C code into something a little less repetitious:

```
enum { STEP1, STEP2, STEP3, /*...*/ };

typedef int ThingToTry();

ThingToTry *things_to_try[MAX_STEP] = {
    try_something,
    try_next_thing,
    /*...*/
};

int next_step (int (*thing_to_try)(), int true_step, int false_step) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPT; i++) {
        if (thing_to_try()) return true_step;
    }
    return false_step;
}

/*...*/

    step = STEP1;
    while (step != MAX_STEP) {
        if (step == STEP1) {
            /*...initialization */
        }
        step = next_step(things_to_try[step], step+1, STEP1);
    }
```

The corresponding code in Java:

```
enum StepEnum { STEP1, STEP2, STEP3, //...
              }

interface ThingToTry {
   bool do_it ();
}

class TrySomething extends ThingToTry //...
class TryNextThing extends ThingToTry //...

StepEnum next_step (ThingToTry thing_to_try,
                    StepEnum true_step, StepEnum false_step) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPTS; ++i) {
        if (thing_to_try.do_it()) return true_step;
    }
    return false_step;
}

//...
    ThingToTry[MAX_STEP] things_to_try = {
        new TrySomething,
        new TryNextThing,
        //...
    };

    while (step != MAX_STEP) {
        if (step == STEP1) {
            //...initialization
        }
        StepEnum true_step = StepEnum.values()[step.ordinal()+1];
        step = next_step(things_to_try[step.ordinal()], true_step, STEP1);
    }
```

Comment: This is cute, but OP asked for refactoring into Java and this ain't Java.

Comment: @TedHopp: I was refactoring the C code first.

Answer (score 0):

What works best for me is splitting logic across functions, here's what I'm thinking:

```
bool attempt_something() {
   for(int i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPT: i++) {
      if (try_something())
         return true;
   }
   return false;
}

bool attempt_something_else() {
   for(int i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPT: i++) {
      if (try_something_else())
         return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

and your while will become

```
while (1) {
   if (!attempt_something())
      continue;
   if (!attempt_something_else())
      continue;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by translating the code to object-oriented design in C. Your code is essentially a state machine, so you should be able to replace it with one.

Example of a typical, function pointer-based state machine:

```
typedef bool (state_t*)(void);

state_t state [STATES_N] = {   // array of function pointers
  &try_something,
  &try_next_thing,
  ...
};


int state = 0;  

while (1) {

  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPT; i++) {

    if(try[state]()) {
      state++;
      if(state == STATES_N) {
        state = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To translate that to Java OO, I suppose you would swap each state for an object of a class, where the class has a try function.